# How to install the Pantheon desktop environment?

Tags: software-installation, pantheon

I want to install Pantheon desktop environment from elementaryOS on Ubuntu, is that possible?

Comment: Having no desire to go backwards...with this desktop environment, what is the suitable kernel? Will it run on the 2.38.xxx or the 3.0.0.0 better. Can I install it on 10.04 10.10 11.04 or 11.10? Be it that you answered your own question. Are you able to provide details

Comment: there is no conf.sh in /elementaryos after do the steps described above... ??

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is answer for newer releases of Ubuntu — 12.04 and up. Remember, **use this at your own risk!**

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Add the repositories and update the package list:

  ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
   sudo apt update
  ```
- Upgrade your packages...

  ```
   sudo apt upgrade
  ```
- ...and install:

  ```
   sudo apt install elementary-desktop
  ```

After completed installation log out and chose session called *Pantheon* in LightDM.

Comment: Not for 12.04 and up, more like only for 12.04.

Comment: If there are some errors please tell me, I stopped using Pantheon a while ago :/

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.10 I get the packet `elementary-desktop` cannot be found

Comment: same here elementary desktop cannot be found

Comment: Is there a stable repo?

Comment: @ZDroid I have done the same in my LinuxMint 17.3 mate machine, elementary-desktop is not showing in the login screen.

What is the problem? Is it because, I have installed cinnamon separately?

Comment: I know it's Ubuntu forum but want to complain this doesn't work on Debian 8 too

Comment: I've installed it on Ubuntu 14.04 and it ruined the desktop manager. Uninstalling also didn't solved the issue. I had to switch to a new desktop manager (Gnome in my case).

Comment: Can I install it on a 16.04lts version of Ubuntu? I want to install Elementary Loki Desktop.

Answer (score 20):

1. Open a terminal window (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Run these commands line by line in the terminal:

   ```
   bzr branch lp:elementaryos
   cd elementaryos
   sudo sh congrego.sh --configure-installed
   ```
3. Logout?Restart and select Pantheon on the login screen.

[image: [Pantheon]

Comment: what effect does this have on the system? Can I undo the changes? Can I use both pantheon and gnome in parallel, choosing one at login?

Comment: @Lightbreeze it is in development so it is a bit risky and can damage your system but yes you can use both in parallel.

Comment: This seems to want to build the entire elementary os and not just pantheon.

Comment: @Alaukik can you specify howto just install `pantheon` on ubuntu 12.10 ? Can't seem to find the instructions anywhere.

Comment: @nikhil Try [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/262834/45853).

Comment: ~/elementaryos$ sudo conf.sh --configure-installed
sudo: conf.sh: command not found What should I do

Comment: @J.A.F try solution from my answer.

Comment: @J.A.F it's called "congrego.sh" so just run `sudo sh congrego.sh --configure-installed`

Answer (score 14):

All answers work but they install the unstable builds, so if you want the stable builds use Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

Now, after you login to Pantheon Desktop it will still look like regular Ubuntu, to easily modify its appearance install Elementary Tweaks:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:versable/elementary-update
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

The `Elementary Tweaks` app is an icon at the main `System Settings`. Change all possible entries to elementary at `Appearance` tab.

You may want to install more apps from Elementary, but with this you get most of it.

Answer (score 9):

I would try their PPA https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/daily

To add it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

The new dock, Plank, is in its own PPA: and so is its browser:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/docky && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:midori/midori-dev
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop plank midori
```

I havent been able to install beatbox too.

EDIT: Please note that this was written in 2011, and it may or may not be still valid for the latest editions of ubuntu. If anyone has tried it, please report in the comments.

Comment: This works, but you don't need to install Midori or Docky from their repos. Look at my answer above.

Answer (score 6):

*All the other answers are, I think, outdated. This question still shows pretty high on some Google searches (that's how I got here), so I'll add this*:

I just installed pantheon on **Ubuntu 14.04**. It's working fine, with just a couple of caveats.

Also, this Ubuntu install has had almost every Desktop Environment under the sun, so it's nothing close to a clean Ubuntu.

Here's how I did it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop elementary-tweaks
```

I'll try to fix what is not working, but it's completely usable. Two exceptions, at least for me on this PC:

- Elementary's official theme looks broken; other themes for Pantheon I've tried too; Lubuntu-default, Ambiance and Radiance, and Adwaita look fine.
- Switchboard, the control panel, crashes if I click on certain elements; I can configure anything with the keyboard (tab to move between elements, arrows and space to change their value.)
- Hotkeys are not the same as in a real Elementary OS, and that's the only thing I can't change on Switchboard; you have the typical Ubuntu hotkeys, which is not that bad. For instance, I prefer switching workspaces with `SUPR+LEFT/RIGHT`, but this has `CTRL+ALT+LEFT/RIGHT`.

If I fix those I might remember to update this. If I don't, feel free to remind me.

Comment: Have you fixed the theme and other issues yet? @jesusiniesta

Comment: @AboudZakaria Sorry, I gave up long ago.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:midori/midori-dev
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:nemequ/sqlheavy
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ricotz/docky
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y pantheon-shell pantheon dexter-contacts postler midori lingo beatbox wingpanel plank lightdm-webkit-greeter pantheon-lightdm-theme pantheon-terminal pantheon-xsession-settings contractor slingshot-launcher scratch marlin elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme exe-wrapper ttf-droid footnote maya switchboard plank-theme-pantheon snap feedler switchboard-gnome-control-center preload
```

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package beatbox
E: Unable to locate package exe-wrapper` on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Comment: It will get the whole elementary OS customizations. Of course you don't clutter your desktop? I only install the core desktop.