# Ugly menus after install Pantheon

Tags: installation, elementary, pantheon

I have this problem about all menus after install Pantheon, I don't have any idea how to fix it. Please help me i'm pretty new to this thing.

[image]

I know it has to do with the theme or something.

Thank you all!

Comment: Do you have any other desktop environments installed?  How did you install Pantheon?

Comment: Yes! The first thing i did was install Pantheon, so i have also Unity, and here is how i install it http://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-do-i-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment Can you helpme? :(

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I'm getting this too.  I think you need to change a theme, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary fix for this.

I logged in to Unity and purged all of Pantheon with

```
sudo apt-get purge elementary-desktop plank midori
```

and then ran

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I then changed Unity's theme to Adwaita and reinstalled Pantheon with

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop plank midori
```

On logging into Pantheon again the menus look just fine.

[image]

I don't like the rest of Adwaita though, so I will probably remove Pantheon until this bug is fixed.