# Wanting to install the Pantheon desktop environment within Ubuntu, is it still dangerous to try to install it or has a stable version been released?

Tags: pantheon

Dangerous as in breaking certain elements of Ubuntu (or installed desktop environments)?

Actually I was looking though a list of all(or most) desktop environments available for Ubuntu and Pantheon looks quite interesting so I thought I would install it and give it a try.

Usually I tend to do a bit of research before installing desktop environments so that I don't end up with a desktop environment I hate or end up just leaving to "collect dust".

I know you can uninstall DEs, but there are some things that sometimes cannot be simply uninstalled without going through some sort of hassle to remove, that's why I'm cautious before deciding to install some things.

Anyways....back on topic....

One thing that seemed to be a reoccurring theme when searching topics/posts etc. was that people were experiencing problems after installing the Pantheon shell/DE(whichever one it actually is). They seemed to be running into Pantheon breaking something on their Ubuntu installation. But all of the posts/threads etc. that I looked at or found were from 2013 or earlier.

So that leads me to my question:

1. Has a "version" of Pantheon been released that is stable(or at least stable enough) that doesn't end up breaking something of my Ubuntu(Ubuntu 13.10) installation(including the additional desktop environments I've downloaded)?
2. If it's a yes to #1, how would you go by installing it from the terminal?

Comment: I don't think you understood or read my question correctly. I'm asking if an updated version the Pantheon desktop environment/shell is available to install on Ubuntu that won't break any available desktop environment/shell available for Ubuntu. There is nothing subjective about a question like that.

Comment: I've installed Pantheon before and it didn't break anything that I can recall. I just followed the answers here: http://askubuntu.com/q/66757/44179

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this i referred it useful for me try this link in ask Ubuntu  [How to install the Pantheon desktop environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment)