# How install elementary os desktop on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, elementary-theme

I found that this command install elementary os

```
$ sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

but the package cannot be located so please help.

Comment: Try this question: [How to install the Pantheon desktop environment?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment)

Answer (score 2):

First remember, installing Elementary Desktop on Ubuntu 14.04 may make your system unstable because it is still in testing.
So I would suggest you to trying it first  on VM.

To install  Elementary Desktop on Ubuntu 14.04, open terminal and execute following commands

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

Comment: I don't think that `ppa:elementary-os/stable` have much package for Ubuntu 14.04, because it is showing only one package for trusty.

Comment: yeah -  the existing question on this just use the daily PPA - I don't think the [stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable) has been updated for atleast a year - never mind.

Comment: what if I want to install stable version do I have do that sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable instead of testing do I need change ?