# Can't login to Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrade

Tags: login, 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 (dual boot with Win 10) and it doesn't login after.
I upgraded from Ubuntu 15.10 via `update-manager`

I have tried old workarounds for previous versions, like:

- `dpkg-reconfigure lightDM`
- `chown user:user .Xauthority`
- `chmod 666 .Xauthority`
- `chmod a+wt /temp`
- `mv .Xauthority smth`
- `apt-get install ubuntu-session`
- Reinstalling Nvidia Drivers

Any suggestions appre

Comment: Reset Unity configuration. Howto: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Comment: @Squirrel , sorry(( but doesn't help
`unity --reset`

Comment: They keep marking these as duplicates, but the old solution doesn't work. I wiped my system because i got fed up and learned it has to do with 3rd party driver issues along with secure boot. Still havnt figured it out yet though. Reported a ton of bugs, were not alone so im hoping its fixed soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install DKMS modules in Ubuntu 16.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules-in-ubuntu-16)

Comment: Which kernel are you using? I got the problem when I was using kernel 4.6.0-rc5. Thanks.

Comment: After days of unsuccessful googling, I posted my problem on https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/board/98/   Nvidia responded with the correct answer in less than an hour. I never would have figured this out with their help.

Answer (score 32):

I was in the same situation as you.

I did not reinstall nvidia drivers but remove it.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

And it worked.

Comment: I did the same, and it worked. But, you know, this is not the final solution if one wants to use a second monitor with the support of nVidia cards!

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: This solution worked for me, somewhat.  It solved my immediate problem, but it isn't really a final solution to the problem.  I also still can't run gdm3 with this change, but lightdm now works.  The real problem seems to be an incompatibility between the new kernels and the nvidia drivers (which worked fine for me before I did the upgrade).  I find it sad that this wasn't better tested before it was released, and that it still hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: This needs to be higher. Happened to me on two very different systems with nvidia cards while dist-upgrading to 17.04 Zesty. Watch for flickering and black screen after login to see if the graphics driver is the issue. 

First the purge, then the reinstall of the latest nvidia from 17.04 (`nvidia-375`) remedied the issue. In case of an Optimus Prime laptop, installation of `nvidia-375 nvidia-prime` was sufficient.

Comment: Same issue after installing Radeon driver. Had to do a `sudo apt purge fglrx*` unfortunately.

Comment: works for me !!! thx

Answer (score 8):

On all my systems (all had the same problem) the solution was:

- Switch to console using Ctrl+Alt+F1
- Login to text console (your username is enough if your system only has one user. otherwise you will need root user or sudo)
- `rm /home/*/.Xauthority`
- `reboot`

Comment: This helped me (thanks), but it's not what the OP asked (he listed that he already did `mv .Xauthority smth`

Comment: @smth The difference is that the OP only moved away the `.Xauthority` of one user...

Comment: This seamlessly worked for me, without resorting to other suggestions that involve uninstalling or reinstalling components.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem on my upgrade to 16.04 from 15.10.  I recalled that during the upgrade, there was a prompt regarding UEFI Secure Boot options.  I checked my BIOS settings and sure enough, Secure Boot was set to "Windows Only".  I selected "Other OS" from the list (your options may be different) and booted normally.  All fixed.

Have not seen any other mentions of this fix so hopefully this will help.

Comment: I'd like to confirm that it fixed my problem too. Was upgrading a brand new  Dell Precision from 14.04 to 16.04 and going into setup I disabled the Secure Boot and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem to.
This problem reason is the new Unity match with `4.4.0` kernel version, and your kernel version same as `4.2.x` now You have 2 solution for this problem:

1. temp: install another desktop env same as `gnome`,`lxde`,or etc...
2. or update the kernel.

for run the command before or after loop <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>:

for check kernel version: send this command

```
$ uname -a
```

and fore update kernel :

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-4-in-ubuntu/

for install other desktop env googling about your desktop env.

Comment: I am using Linux kernel 4.6.0-rc5 and GNOME 3.20.1, but still experiencing the problem. Thoughts?

Comment: Try to install `elementary-desktop ` for fixing : http://askubuntu.com/questions/529715/how-install-elementary-os-desktop-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

I just tried Nuno's idea..  Negative for me..  still stuck in the login loop on Console-7.. But, able to log in via console 1 (TTY1)..  I also ran into this back when i went the route of 12.10 to 13.x (both), and it landed in the same loop..  Only workaround I could find, was using an old "Installed" software list from Synaptic, doing a fresh install of 13.04, and also doing the same when i bumped up to 15.04.  , getting Synaptic loaded 1st, and then reading in the old software list.

Comment: just tried another idea, and this one WORKS!   Log in via TTY1.. Now, enter the following:  [code] sudo mv .Xauthority .xAuthority.old [/code]  reboot, and it worked!

Comment: Apparently, I missed a step.. It also requires re-installing LightDM from scratch..    [code] sudo apt-get purge lightdm ; sudo apt-get install lightdm  -y [/code], as well as removing all of the nvidia drivers... (insert head hung low..)