# Unable to get to desktop on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, unity, 16.04, login

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 for a couple of months now without any problems.  However, since 2 days ago I got a message on start up saying `System Program Problem Detected`. I have had the same message on my laptop, which is running 14.04, for quite a long time now without any issues, so I just ignored it.

Now, however, my 16.04 installation cannot login anymore. I get the login screen, I enter my account credentials, and after this I get the familiar `System Program Problem Detected` message but I can not see anything else of the (Unity) Desktop. After 2 seconds, the screen goes black and after this I am again presented with the login screen. I can repeat this cycle indefinitely.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I tried booting in recovery mode already but that was to no avail.

Comment: When grub starts up the second option is `advanced options` where you can pick an older kernel version. Have you tried that to see if it's a new problem introduced with kernel upgrade?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have just tried that - same result :/

Comment: you can try this solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade/369297

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix those solutions did not work either

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/759871/cant-login-to-ubuntu-16-04-after-upgrade   , try the second solution ( rm /home/*/.Xauthority )

Comment: @laugeo I tried this as well. Because my desktop always had problems with Linux systems in the past ~5 years I have set it up so it is mostly disposable. Ended up reinstalling, took 15 min and then 15 more to get everything on it again that I needed. 

Thanks for the suggestions guys, unfortunately I lost more time trying to fix this than just reinstalling :D