# kubuntu 16.04 LTS: apt-get upgrade causes issues with login and black desktop with no toolbar

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kubuntu, desktop-environments

Having Kubuntu 16.04 LTS for half a year, I have performed the following innocent `sudo apt-get upgrade`, which resulted in installation of plenty of packages. After this upgrade the design of a login screen changed and I could not get over it. Logging in, I would get the black screen and a total freeze of the computer.

- First hypothesis was that the issue is caused by malfunction of nVIDIA drivers, which was rejected after plenty of hopeless attempts to reinstall drivers.
- I also tried to reinstall `kubuntu-desktop, plasma-desktop, xorg, sddu` without any observable result.
- I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as well with no positive result.

Luckily, I have spotted that the `~/.Xauthority` file has wrong permissions and following the advice to delete that file I got one step further. [Can't login to Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759871/cant-login-to-ubuntu-16-04-after-upgrade)

Now, I can log in (and luckily work). I get a black screen and a cursor. I see no tool bar at the bottom of the screen, no widgets, no wallpaper. The system has forced a new theme of windows called Breeze. I have to get the Internet connectivity by myself in terminal via `nmcli n off; nmcli n on`. I can run all applications using `alt + F2` runner. But the start up of the applications is very slow. Shutting down the system is extremely slow as well.

Can anyone give me a good advice which part of the system is responsible for this issue and how to fix it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to add a repository with a new plasma desktop release and reinstall it fully from this repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

For more info see: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-latest-plasma-desktop-kubuntu-16-04