# Ubuntu 14.04 Pantheon session not shown in LightDM

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, elementary, pantheon

I installed elementary-desktop on my Ubuntu 14.04 x64 virtual machine following [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment), but I don't get the Pantheon session in LightDM.
I only have KDE Plasma Workspace and Ubuntu(Default).

Is there any way I can add it?