# Installed Pantheon on Ubuntu 14.04, can't access it

Tags: 14.04, session, elementary

I have installed Elementary OS's Pantheon on Ubuntu 14.04 following the instructions in here [installation guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment).

After doing what the first answer says, I rebooted and found that there is no icon to choose a session on the login page. Upon logging onto Ubuntu, however, I notice that there exists the Elementary theme and a few other things so it's not like nothing was installed... But still I cannot access it.

I then followed the instructions on the second answer, but once again it was to no avail. No way to choose another session.

What can I do?

Comment: Which answer did you follow from that question?

Comment: @muru As I wrote above, I followed the first two... I tried the most up-voted one and when I saw that it (seemingly) failed, I tried the second most up-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well, long story short answer: There is currently no way to install or run Pantheon on Ubuntu (or any other distro, for that matter) in a stable and sane way.
>
> Let's talk about why: Although elementary OS (Freya) is based on Ubuntu (14.04), some core packages are patched or backported (= we imported a newer version of the package). You experienced this problem with the GTK+ library (a very popular toolkit for writing GUI applications).
>
> We do not maintain versions of Pantheon for other distros than elementary OS, because there are simply no ressources (in terms of developers) left to do so. It's a very complicated thing to write applications for different distros (because of the different versions of libraries) - and let's not talk about a whole desktop environment depending on GNOME tools and libs.
>
> Oh and you shouldn't add elementary PPAs (which are our repos currently) because this may/will overwrite libs and stuff. I fear you will only bork your system with doing so!

https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2y60m5/new_issues_with_elementary_desktop_on_ubuntu1404/

Comment: Yep, it did bork my system. Ended up doing a clean installation. Thanks!