# Problem after Install Elementary OS desktop in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, elementary

I installed Elementary-Desktop from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment)

After install I log out and in the session does not show **Pantheon** for login in LightDM. Why?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am afraid Elementary is off-topic here. Please try https://elementary.io/en/support or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  He's asking about installing the desktop from Elementary on Ubuntu, which is a possible duplicate of the question he's linked to.

Comment: i have install pantheon and it is not active for me!

Comment: Completely restart LightDM by Ctrl+Alt+Backspace (if configured) or simply reboot.

Comment: I reboot my Ubuntu and not showing.

Comment: @CarlH Ah, sorry, sorry, retracted my vote...

Comment: @Digicom which answer did you use, and have you tried any of the others?

Comment: I use a video from Youtube and install, but it is not useful and nice!

Comment: It is answer, no question. step for question is in link.

Comment: This answer was not to be understood as an answer. https://askubuntu.com/revisions/631011/1

Comment: NO! not duplicated.

Comment: It is a duplicate, Digicom. Not sure why you are trying to pass it off as something else.

Answer (score 0):

I used below code and it is install and work for me:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

Comment: That's better than the previous version.

Comment: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing; sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop` is enough. You don't need `sudo apt-get update` twice.