# White area behind transpared gnome terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, desktop-environments, pantheon

[image]

I tried to install pantheon on ubuntu 16.04.1 with ppa. 
After the installation pantheon was not available as a desktop so i removed it. but after that the while the gnome terminal was transpired there is a white area behind it as you see in the image.

I am using gnome 3.20

I installed Pantheon desktop from the elementary-os daily repository. Link - [How to install the Pantheon desktop environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-to-install-the)

And gnome 3.20 from the gnome3-team repository. Link - http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/how-to-install-gnome-320-in-ubuntu.html?m=1

Comment: Where did you install pantheon from and gnome 3.20?

Comment: May you help please?

Comment: I suggest to remove gnome 3.20 using ppa-purge as directed by the webup8 link.

Comment: Does it solve the problem?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but that can do. Also try creating a new user and see if that user too have this problem