# Elementary OS Loki 0.4 Desktop on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, elementary, elementary-theme

how to setup Elementary OS Loki 0.4 Desktop on ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: Elementary OS and Ubuntu are different operating systems and are not "interchangeable" like you think.  eOS is also offtopic here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: ok. can we just setup that desktop on 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

At least on Debian, you can install the pantheon desktop. I don't see why it shouldn't work on Ubuntu as well

[How to install the Pantheon desktop environment?](https://askubuntu.com/q/66757/548587)