# How to install elementary os loki in ubuntu 16.10 without using iso file

Tags: 16.10, elementary

How can I install Elementary OS Loki in Ubuntu 16.10 without using the iso file? And having to change my partitions (which I know very little about). Upon trying to install EOS using the steps indicated (via the ppa) I get the error message: E: Unable to locate package elementary-desktop. Is one of the other methods there supposed to work for EOS under Ubuntu 16.10?

The `elementary-desktop` package is missing from the PPA, so this is not a duplicate of [How to install the Pantheon desktop environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I must apologize here for being (though unintentional) somewhat misleading. What I am ultimately looking for is a safe method of running both Ubuntu 16.10 and Elementary Loki OS together. I am perfectly happy downloading the iso file (which I have just done) and rebooting my machine to install it. However, the reason I wanted to install from ppa and that alone is that I am uncertain how to configure my partition scheme so that EOS and Ubuntu both share my home directory and so that I do not loose any data in the process.

Within that framework can anyone please assist me?

Thanks,

-MD

Comment: To be clear, you want to install EOS on or over Ubuntu?

Comment: I want to install EOS in ubuntu so that at start-up I have the option of choosing either.

Comment: When I try to use the ppa, I get the following: 'Unable to locate package elementary-desktop'. What can I do from here?

Comment: When I follow the steps there I keep getting the following in the terminal: 'E: Unable to locate package elementary-desktop'

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but are any of these "solutions" applicable for Ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: I am looking in to it for you, please be patient. I will get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Did you perhaps try [this one](http://askubuntu.com/a/66759/225694)?

Comment: The Elementary OS installer should detect your existing OS and offer to install alongside for you. Just try it. Installing Elementary OS is off-topic here. So this question will likely be closed for one reason or another, However you may find [this](http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-elementary-loki-usb-dual-boot/) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) useful. Another option would be to simply install virtualbox and run EOS loki as a VM under the Ubuntu host.

Comment: I would recommend against sharing home directories between distros. You may get away with it for a period of time but as there is a great deal of hidden configuration data stored there things can easily get out of sync after a normal update procedure and break things. If you aren't greatly experienced with fixing what you've broken it would be far safer for you  to simply share specific folders inside home that contain your data (Documents, Videos, Music, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

Kindly refer to the steps on [this](http://lmelinux.net/2016/03/26/install-elementary-os-loki-system-now/) website.
Here is the extract of this website:

1. Download Ubuntu 16.04 Beta 2 and install it on your system.
2. Once installed, add elementary daily PPA by typing the following in Terminal:

   `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily`
3. Update the system and install elementary-desktop package:

   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be using the elementary daily PPA rather than the stable.  The stable PPA is still only supporting 16.04/xenial while the daily does include packages for 16.10/yakkety.  The daiily is [here](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily).  Once you have added the PPA, apt update, apt install elementary-desktop should work.