# install pantheon desktop on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10, pantheon

I was wondering if it was possible to install the pantheon desktop from elementary-os on a ubuntu 16.10 ?

thx

Comment: It is possible but I would recommend not doing it. Because I have done it before and it always brakes unity.

Comment: I'm on a fresh minimal install, i don't have unity currently installed :)

Comment: What exactly did you do and what happened? I can see the package sitting right there in the PPA for Zesty: https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily/+sourcepub/7130818/+listing-archive-extra

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the Pantheon desktop environment?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment)

Comment: as said before, the instructions on  [How to install the Pantheon desktop environment?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment) are not working for me. what I did is what Liso posted below and I receive the following errors during apt-get update`E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/testing/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

Comment: also ubuntu 16.10 is not **Zesty** but **Yakkety**...

Answer (score 3):

To install Pantheon DE on 16.10, run following command in order:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop
```

Various user reportedly has encountered couple of bugs, since this procedure will install the unstable version. Other than that, it's completely usable and working fine.

Comment: thanks for you response but this is not working on 16.10

Answer (score 0):

edit the source list of elementary os ppa:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary-os-ubuntu-daily-zesty.list
```

after that change "zesty" or name of version of ubuntu with "xenial" like as:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu xenial main
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```